# Support for RTL in Android PagerSlidingTabStrip library

Tags: android, right-to-left

I've downloaded [this](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) lib project `PagerSlidingTabStrip` for Android and am working on it.

Everything is working okay except for one thing, it dose not support `RTL` charset. How can I make tabs appear from `right to left` instead of from `left to right`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste the code in your libaray above `"tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);"`

```
tabsContainer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```